# Is it possible to analytically find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

$M$ is a $R \times R$ dimensional square matrix. The elements of $M$ are
\begin{align}
[M]_{nm} &= R \hspace{3 cm} when \hspace{.2 cm} n=m, \\
       &= \frac{1-e^\frac{2\pi i R (n-m)}{f}}{1-e^\frac{2\pi i  (n-m)}{f}} \hspace{1 cm} when \hspace{.2 cm} n \neq m ,
\end{align}
where $n$, $m$ are row and column indices respectively and $f$ is a mixed fraction not larger than $R+1$. Is it possible to analytically find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$?

Comment: Can you do small cases?  $R=1, R=2$ ?

Comment: you would have better luck writing that as the geometric sum and do some column operations to delete some of the summands. As it is, I do not recall it fits into well-known determinants like Cauchy, Toeplitz, circular, tridiagonal, Vandermonde etc, even after simplifying the fraction with some de'Moivre's formulae etc.

Comment: actually it does seem circulant since $M_{mn}$ is only dependent on $|m-n|$, so you can calculate everything - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Comment: It is obviously Toeplitz, but in the Toeplitz-only case you don't get explicit analytical results for the eigendata. So yeah, it comes down to showing it is circulant, which is not staring you in the face from the way you wrote it down.